# Jpa Issues in Production

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We are working on a banking domain application, it is built on jboss seam with JPA (Hibernate) Some times on production environment we get some issues related to hibernate .

When ever we are registering the customers to DB, same record is created twice in DB when user click the action button twice.(it happen some times not regularly)

To avoid this we validate the record in coding level with existing db .

can you please suggest is there any problem with JPA ?

Comment: Disable the button after the user clicks it, when the server respond the request, enable it back. The JPA framework is working as designed. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that this happens when user clicks the action button twice so i think it is not the problem of JPA.

You will have to use a flag in method so that it will know that how many times button is clicked.and it will submit a single request.